# ¿Como puedo hacer para que un boton se llame automaticamente desde otro metodo?

Tags: java, java-swing

Como puedo hacer para lo programado en un boton `jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)` se ejcute aumtomaticamente desde otro metodo

Comment: Desde el otro método utiliza una referencia al botón y llama a ``button.doClick()``, esto ejecuta el código del botón como si se hubiese pulsado https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#doClick--

Answer (score 2):

Para hacer esto, desde el otro método utiliza una referencia al botón y llama a `button.doClick()`, eso ejecuta el código del botón como si se hubiese pulsado

Ref: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#doClick--

Aquí hay un ejemplo simple, imagínate que ya tienes la interfaz y tienes un botón creado, ahora desde otro método utiliza una referencia al botón para ejecutar el método `doClick()`, sea directamente o utilizando un getter

```
private JButton button;

public Test() {
    button = new JButton();
    
    button.addActionListener(e -> {
        System.out.println("Hola mundo");
    });
    
    execute();
}

private void execute() {
    button.doClick();
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias funciona perfecto!